# Review articles on the rule-following paradox

Tags: wittgenstein, paradox, private-language

Except for the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (SEP) article on private language, I am having a hard time finding review articles (or book chapters) on the rule-following paradox.

What review articles should I read? I want articles that present more modern/contemporary positions (argument), not just traditional ones.

Comment: See [Azzouni's](https://as.tufts.edu/philosophy/sites/all/themes/asbase/assets/documents/azzouniRuleFollowingParadox.pdf) (he also has a book), [Smith's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0732118X08000135) and [Wrisley's](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00048402.2010.495131) papers for some recent takes. [Ellis-Guevara](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199737666.001.0001/acprof-9780199737666-chapter-5) have a chapter on it.

Comment: [Miller's 2020 paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/dialogue-canadian-philosophical-review-revue-canadienne-de-philosophie/article/verheggen-on-davidson-and-kripke-on-rulefollowing-and-meaning/EEF95E3243F30EBFD929D8A83974547C) is also more of a review.